# Retrieving Metadata and Choosing Appropriate Components

Tags: angular, metadata

I’m working on an angular project where I have the metadata from the API but I need to retrieve it, identify the component “type” and display the respective components on the screen. I was thinking I would retrieve and convert to JSON? Any other approaches? How can I do that

```
0: {label: "Valid From", type: "MSKDR", value: "XXXXX"}
1: {label: “Address key", type: "DRPD", value: "XXXXX"}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you add more description